# Postgresql wal log limiting (RDS)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, wal

We're using Debezium as a change data capture connector for PostgreSQL (actually RDS).

If for any reason the debezium connector has a terminal failure, the WAL will continue to grow until either debezium is fixed, or the server runs out of storage space.

Is it possible to set a limit on the size a WAL can grow?

I've looked into https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/max_wal_size/ and am not convinced it will do what we need.

Basic architecture is:

Events > Postgres > debezium > Events

In an ideal world if WAL hits a limit events hitting postgres will error as the wal log cannot be written to. Upon restoring debezium and it picking up the WAL log it should read/clear and continue then to process new events.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Seems that you are attempting to fix the wrong problem. You would be better off mentoring and then fixing your  terminal failure,.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the PostgreSQL configuration parameter `max_slot_wal_keep_size` to the desired limit of WAL you want to retain. If that limit is exceeded, PostgreSQL will remove WAL, and you will have to rebuild the replication.

Comment: when you say "remove WAL" what do you mean please? Ideally what I'm after is when it hits a limit PSQL stops accepting new data. We then come in and fix the change data capture, and it will then process what was in the overgrown WAL and continue on from there to accept data.

Thank you

Comment: There is no way to prevent PostgreSQL from accepting new connections short of stopping the server.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, there is no way to do set a limit to WAL size. As long as there is an activity(modification) in your database, the wal logs will be generated; otherwise your database processes will be halted. Only limitation is of course is the storage size, but if you hit that limit as I mentioned database will be halted. This is my answer to your question.

In addition to your question, I don' t know how Debezium works, but in Oracle GoldenGate there was a concept called data pumps. In order to deal woth this kind of scenario you need to transfer CDC logs to target server or another server if you have a strict storage limitation on the database server. Afterwards, Debezium needs to read from the file and apply or streams the changes on the target side if there is similar approach in Debezium. So, the CDC replication/stream is not directly from database server to target. It should be from database server to the file and then from file to target.

Comment: Thank you Umut. That was my fear. WAL logs can become enormous quickly causing prod issues. It's a real balancing act with RDS storage - not wanting to over provision, but at the cost of 30mins downtime whilst expanding the storage to make the DB accessible again.